# How to merge multiple data frames by multiple columns in R

Tags: r, list, merge, reduce

I've been trying to figure out a way to stitch together 6 data frames that I'm working with that have about 50 columns that I want to match together.

End goal is to combine all rows from each dataset under their shared column names into one large dataset with my relevant columns of interest. Each dataset varies slightly in the amount of rows, but all column names of interest will match.

Wondering what way would be the best to go about this? I've been unable to figure out how to merge more than 2 dfs by multiple columns!

```
merge_data1 <- list(hos_2015_data, hos_2016_data, hos_2017_data, 
              hos_2018_data, hos_2019_data, hos_2020_data, hos_2021_data)
merged_result1 <- merge_data1 %>%
   reduce (full_join, by= "Facility.ID")
View (merged_result1)
```

This only matched by the one column "Facility.ID", but I have MANY more columns I want to match too!

Comment: Base `merge` can handle an arbitrary number of data frames but I don’t know about `full_join`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Can we have a [mcve] please? I think you want `merge_data1 %>% reduce(~full_join(., by = c(key1, key2, key3, ...)))` ...

Comment: When you say "all column names of interest will match" does that mean that they have some of the same data columns and you actually want to bind them into a longer data frame?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple data frames with many matching columns, I suspect you want `bind_rows` and not a join. `bind_rows` will result in a longer data frame that "stacks" the component data frames, whereas a join will result in a wider dataframe. joins are typically used where there are one or more "key" columns that are common to the multiple data frames, but the other columns are typically unique to each data frame, and you want to combine them into one data frame. If you have multiple years of data where the data is stored in matching column names, but the number of rows vary, that sounds more like you want to bind the composite rows.

```
library(dplyr)
storms_2015 <- subset(storms, year == 2015)
storms_2016 <- subset(storms, year == 2016)
storms_2017 <- subset(storms, year == 2017)

bind_rows(storms_2015, storms_2016, storms_2017)
```

Result (includes all the data from the three data frames)

```
# A tibble: 1,535 × 13
   name   year month   day  hour   lat  long status            category  wind pressure tropicalstorm_force_diameter hurricane_force_diameter
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>                <dbl> <int>    <int>                        <int>                    <int>
 1 Ana    2015     5     6     6  26.8 -79.2 other low               NA    25     1016                            0                        0
 2 Ana    2015     5     6    12  28.2 -78.5 other low               NA    25     1015                            0                        0
 3 Ana    2015     5     6    18  29.7 -77.8 other low               NA    25     1014                            0                        0
 4 Ana    2015     5     7     0  30.8 -77.5 other low               NA    30     1012                            0                        0
 5 Ana    2015     5     7     6  30.7 -77.8 other low               NA    35     1010                          100                        0
 6 Ana    2015     5     7    12  30.6 -77.5 other low               NA    40     1008                          210                        0
 7 Ana    2015     5     7    18  31.2 -77.5 other low               NA    40     1005                          220                        0
 8 Ana    2015     5     8     0  31.4 -77.6 subtropical storm       NA    40     1003                          220                        0
 9 Ana    2015     5     8     6  31.5 -77.6 subtropical storm       NA    40     1002                          220                        0
10 Ana    2015     5     8    12  31.5 -77.5 subtropical storm       NA    40     1000                          210                        0
# ℹ 1,525 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I really appreciate your help Jon!

Comment: Does this answer your question?